# Why can't I write to /dev/stdout, but php://stdout works?

Tags: php, linux, apache, docker

I'm trying to write to stdout (or stderr) using PHP with Apache (running in the foreground in Docker).

These works:

```
file_put_contents( "php://stderr","works" );
file_put_contents( "php://stdout","works" );

$fh = fopen('php://stdout','w'); fwrite($fh, "works");
```

But these do not:

```
$stdout = fopen ("/dev/stdout","w"); fwrite($stdout, "fails");
$stderr = fopen ("/dev/stderr","w"); fwrite($stderr, "fails");

echo "fd1 exists:" . (file_exists('/proc/self/fd/1') ? 'yes' : 'no');
echo "fd1 writable:" . (is_writable('/proc/self/fd/1') ? 'yes' : 'no');
echo "stdout exists:" . (file_exists('/dev/stdout') ? 'yes' : 'no');
echo "stdout writable:" . (is_writable('/dev/stdout') ? 'yes' : 'no');

file_put_contents( "/proc/self/fd/1", "fails" );
file_put_contents( "/proc/self/fd/2", "fails" );
file_put_contents( "/dev/stdout", "fails" );

fwrite(STDOUT, 'fails');
fwrite(STDERR, 'fails');
```

/dev/stdout do exist, but is not writable. also `fopen('/dev/stdout')` returns FALSE.

```
fd1 exists:yes
fd1 writable:no
stdout exists:yes
stdout writable:no
```

More info:

- I tried setting `error_log = /dev/stdout` in php.ini, but it doesn't work
- I tried Docker command `RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout stdout.log` and then writing to `stdout.log` in PHP, but nope.

*Again, what is php://stdout doing that I don't?*

Comment: Probably be better answers but did you try `STDOUT` and `STDERR`?  You don't need to open with these, they are already open so just write.

Comment: STDOUT/ERR are only available in CLI afaik. Anyway, they don't work when I try them. Thanks though.

Comment: See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31243. "Permission error received when attempting to write to /dev/stdout as a non-root user"

Comment: @ceejayoz That might be the case, although I did try `chmod 777 /dev/stdout` to no avail. Also, how does that explain why `php://stdout` works and /dev/stdout does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that Apache forks and changes user to a less privileged one (the "apache" user) which does not have permission to write `/dev/stdout`. There is no easy way around this, so I ended up with a script.

The script creates a file (pipe) which is connected through a 'cat' process which writes to standard error (as root):

```
mkfifo -m 600 logpipe
chown apache:apache logpipe
cat <> logpipe 1>&2 &
CAT=$!

# Start apache
/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND

# Kill the cat after apache dies
kill $CAT
```

Now you can set `error_log = logpipe` in php.ini and all php errors will be sent to stderr.

As for why `php://stdout` works, my guess is that PHP uses a file handle (to `/dev/stdout`) which is already opened by Apache.

More details [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6880#issuecomment-344114520).